# SFTP not working

Tags: centos, ssh, sftp

We have a Centos 6 machine, and until today, sftp was working fine. Yesterday we reboot the machine, and now we can connect throught SSH but not SFTP

We have tried with internal-sftp and sftp-server in sshd_config, but anyone works.

In the other hand, we have this log on secure:

```
Oct 21 14:00:19 srvweb01 sshd[16830]: Accepted password for root from X.X.X.X port 64787 ssh2
Oct 21 14:00:19 srvweb01 sshd[16830]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct 21 14:00:25 srvweb01 sshd[16830]: subsystem request for sftp
```

And after 4 minutes, timeout. Of course we tried to reboot service and server, but nothing works.

Thank you,

Comment: Ok, after too many attemps i finnaly can connect, but the server takes TOO MUCH time to list directories, about 1 minute aprox, and the server gives me timeout, but in SSH mode is instant.

Comment: Okay, we have the system working now. The problem was that this is a cloud instante without a valid hostname, so add a FQDN hostname in /etc/hosts and set a hostname, has apparently solved the problem

Comment: Please feel free to [answer your own question](http://serverfault.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, we have the system working now. The problem was that this is a cloud instante without a valid hostname, so add a FQDN hostname in /etc/hosts and set a hostname, has apparently solved the problem.